# In MS Word 2010, copy table cell contents with an image

Tags: microsoft-word

In MS Word 2010, how do I copy a table cell contents with an image and get both the text and the image? When I copy a cell contents, it copies only the text and not the image as well. I have to do 2 copies, one for the text and one for the image. How do I get both in 1 copy?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. Are you highlighting the image and the text, right-clicking on the text, copying, and then pasting? What kind of program or document are you pasting into?

Comment: just as an experiment, I know it will do more, but what if you do ctrl-A then copy and paste, does that include the image? 'cos if that doesn't then nothing will! But it should!